Why is an unpolarized beam considered an incoherent mixture of equal weights?
Edit: The bottom edit is the more accurate question.
In Sakurai’s Modern Quantum Mechanics (p. 174, Example 3), it is explained that an unpolarized beam of photons is represented as an incoherent mixture of states with equal weights for orthogonal polarizations. This seems to imply that the beam is described by a statistical mixture, rather than a superposition of states.
However, I find this puzzling because:

If the mixture is truly random, wouldn’t we need infinitely many terms with infinitely small probabilities to describe it?
Alternatively, does this representation mean that each photon is in a completely determined state with no superposition involved?

Any clarification or insight would be greatly appreciated.
Edit:
I will try to phrase the question more precisely. Sorry, it seemed clearer in my head. The motivation is me trying to understand the density matrix. As I understand it, we basically use it for stating that something is either in one state or another without the coherences present which is what allows quantum phenomena.
If e.g., I have some particle in a superposition, but I do a measurement i.e. force the wavefunction to collapse, but I do not record the answer, as I understand it, it will be in the incoherent mixture of spin-up and spin-down, since in reality it will for sure be in one of these pure states. Hopefully, someone can confirm this.
In Sakurai, it is stated that an unpolarized beam has density matrix:
$$
\rho = \frac{1}{2}|+><+|+\frac{1}{2}|-><-|
$$
I read this as the particle either being in up or down state. But am I right to assume, that this states that no particles are in a superposition. My comment about infinite terms is that I imagine the following: Let's say that we have all possible pure states (pretend normalized)
$$
|0.1>=0.1|+>+0.9|->
$$
$$
|0.2>=0.2|+>+0.8|->
$$
$$
|0.3>=0.3|+>+0.7|->
$$
If the beam was truly a random mixture, would it not contain the possibility of some particle actually being in a superposition. Or are no particles in a superposition when unpolarized just because we imagine that no experiment has been performed that possibly could put it in a superposition.

Could you include some more details? Context, equations etc. (please type those and do not use images/screenshots for math and text)

I don't understand the reasoning behind puzzle-point-number (1).

@TobiasFünke, hopefully it is clearer now with my edit. Thank you for the feedback.

@JEB, ty for the feedback, I tried to the improve the question with my edit.

Thanks for the edit. One more thing: Consider to use \langle and \rangle to get $\langle$ and $\rangle$, respectively.

I don’t understand the last paragraph of your edit.  Maybe read this book by Blum on density matrix theory to untangle some of the knots…

I'm not sure where the problem is.  If you use the eigenstates  $\vert \pm;\hat n\rangle$ for any spin operator $\hat n\cdot \vec S$ where $S_i=\frac12 \sigma_i$, then
$$
\hat\rho = \frac{1}{2} \vert +;\hat n\rangle\langle +;\hat n \vert 
+\frac{1}{2} \vert -;\hat n\rangle\langle -;\hat n \vert
$$
produces $\langle S_x\rangle=\langle S_y\rangle=\langle S_z\rangle=0$, which is the statement that the beam is unpolarized.
Now, since $\vert \pm;\hat n\rangle$ are arbitrary eigenstates, you can use any set of such eigenstates.  They have the property that two equivalent sets $\{\vert \pm;\hat n\rangle\}$ and $\{\vert \pm;\hat n'\rangle\}$ differ by a rotation which physically means that rotating the beam about its symmetry axis will not change the statistics of the beam.

The question then is whether or not this is the only state with this property, no? And the answer is yes if by $S_i$ you mean the usual Pauli matrices modulo multiplicative constants.

The best way to understand polarization coherence is through the Poincare Sphere. When we deal with polarized light, the approach for perfect coherent beams is to describe polarization using the polarization vector. But when we describe partially coherent or incoherent beams, this description is not enough and the best approach is to use the Stokes Parameters. They are defined as
$$
\begin{cases}
S_0 = I\\
S_1 = I \, p \cos(2\theta)\cos(2\phi)\\
S_2 = I \, p \cos(2\theta)\sin(2\phi)\\
S_3 = I\, p \sin(2\phi)\\
\end{cases}
$$
Where $I$ is the total intensity of the light, $p$ is the degree of polarization and the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ are related to the polarization vector of the light. You could find interesting this wiki about the subject.
For $p=1$, you have an equivalent description of perfect polarized beams. The magic happens when we have $p<1$ and in special, the maximally mixed (or totally incoherent or unpolarized) beam represented by $p= 0$. In this above article, you'll find the following figure

That is the Poincare Sphere that I mentioned. The unpolarized state of light is in its center. We have infinite ways to represent the center point as mixtures of points in the surface. We could imagine it as a mixture of uncountable number of points, as your intuition suggested. For a uniform distribution over the sphere $p(\Omega)$, we would find
$$
\int d\Omega \, p(\Omega) \, \hat r(\Omega) = 0
$$
where $\hat r=(S_1,S_2,S_3)$ is any unit vector in the sphere. This is exactly what means to mix all directions with the same probability.
The interesting thing, however, is that, as I mentioned, the decomposition is not unique. If we equally mix two Stokes vectors in the Poincare sphere in opposite directions, we also get the center
$$
\frac 12 \hat z + \frac 12 (-\hat z) = 0
$$
So as the decomposition is not unique, when we talk about the unpolarized state, we choose the simplest way to describe it.
The Poincare sphere maps orthogonal polarization vectors to antipodal Stokes vectors, so the affirmation of Sakurai follows. All of that applies to Classical Light. To account for quantum theory, we could change Polarization Vector to state Vector, Poincare Sphere to Bloch sphere and Stokes vector for Bloch vector.


If the mixture is truly random, wouldn’t we need infinitely many terms with infinitely small probabilities to describe it?

No. One (of several) ways to describe any quantum measurement is a fixed unitary operation H followed by a standard "up vs down" measurement. The measurement probabilities P depend on the H chosen.
But the relationship between H and P is restricted, it is always quadratic in the terms of H. Any such relationship can be encoded with a finite density matrix.
Conceptually a mixed state is a list of pure states with classical
probabilities. This list can be any length. But it's always possible to come up with an equivalent density matrix that will give the same outcomes as the original list no matter how many observations they are allowed to make.

Alternatively, does this representation mean that each photon is in
a completely determined state with no superposition involved?

No. Entanglement cannot be destroyed without carefully reversing the process that produced it. But it easily gets scrambled and rendered useless in an incoherent system or when an entangled Bell pair gets used up by an observation.
Note: Photons are spin 1 particles. So why are there only two measurement outcomes (up and down) instead of three? They are massless.

Thank you. I added an edit. Refering to the parapgraph just above 2. Could this be interpreted as the math just collapsing to the simple equation, but in reality the superpositions are present?

@jeppetm: Yes, but in quantum mechanics often what is "actually happening" is far to complex to model (a necessary condition for get quantum computing to be a thing) or even depict. So many times "what is actually going on" is not ever discussed.



If the mixture is truly random, wouldn’t we need infinitely many terms with infinitely small probabilities to describe it?


Yes, but actually no. Statistical mixtures of quantum states are a bit unintuitive!
Let's say you have a statistical mixture $M_1$ of $1/2$ spin-up photons, and $1/2$ spin-down photons. What happens if we measure the spin of one of those photons along an arbitrary axis? It turns out that, no matter what axis you choose, you'll always get a $+1$ with probability $1/2$ and $-1$ with probability $1/2$.*
Now let's say instead we have a mixture $M_2$ of $1/2$ spin-left photons, and $1/2$ spin-right photons. Now what happens if we take one of those photons and measure it? Well, just like before, we'll always get $+1$ half the time and $-1$ half the time. (This shouldn't be too surprising, since after all there's nothing fundamentally different about the up-down direction compared to the left-right direction.)
Why is this important? We have two different mixtures, and yet any measurement we perform on them gives the same result (well, the same probability distribution of possible results). Since there is no experiment we can do to tell them apart, there is a fundamental sense in which the different mixtures $M_1$ and $M_2$ correspond to the same state. In the language of ZeroTheHero's answer, we would say that both mixtures have the same density matrix; or in the language of Ruffolo's answer, that both mixtures correspond to the same point on the Poincare sphere. But the upshot is that even though these mixtures were created in two different ways, they really are indistinguishable from each other.
Going back to the issue at hand, it seems like your intuition is telling you that the unpolarized state should be a classical mixture of every possible direction of photon, with an infinitesimal probability of each direction - and you're entirely correct! It's just that this state is also indistinguishable from the mixtures $M_1$ or $M_2$, and since the latter are easier to describe we usually just say it's a mixture of half spin-up and half spin-down. It's only a matter of convenience.
*For anyone interested in the math: suppose we take an axis at angle $\theta$ to the $z$-axis. A spin-up photon will measure $+1$ with probability $\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}$, while a spin-down photon will measure $+1$ with probability $\cos^2\frac{\pi-\theta}{2}=\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$. Since spin-up and spin down both occur in the mixture with $1/2$ probability, the overall chance to measure $+1$ is $\frac{1}{2}(\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2} + \sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}$, independent of $\theta$.


Alternatively, does this representation mean that each photon is in a completely determined state with no superposition involved?


There is no such thing as a state without superposition
This is largely unrelated to the above, but it's a very common misconception. Every state is a superposition of other states - it just depends on what you choose as your basis. Often we take a basis of spin-up and spin-down, $|{+}z\rangle$ and $|{-}z\rangle$, and all other states can be written as superpositions of those two. But it's just as valid to use a basis of spin-left and spin-right instead, $|{+}x\rangle$ and $|{-}x\rangle$, and in this basis the spin-up and spin-down states are superpositions; for example, $|{+}z\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|{+}x\rangle+|{-}x\rangle)$. Asking whether a state is a superposition or not is like asking whether a number can be written as the sum of other numbers - the answer is always yes.
Note that this is markedly different from asking whether or not a given state is or is not a classical (aka statistical) mixture of different states. A single quantum state is called a pure state, and a statistical mixture of multiple different pure states is called a mixed state - and whether a state is pure or mixed does not depend on what basis you use to describe it.


This seems to imply that the beam is described by a statistical mixture, rather than a superposition of states.

Indeed, such a mixture is described by a density matrix rather than a wave function. If we had a coherent mixture, with a wave function
$$|z\rangle = \alpha|+\rangle + \beta -\rangle$$, the density matrix would take form
$$
\rho=|z\rangle\langle z|=\begin{bmatrix}|\alpha|^2&\alpha\beta^*\\
\alpha^*\beta&|\beta|^2\end{bmatrix}
$$
It is easy to see that averaging over the wave function and over the density matrix give the same result
$$
\langle z|A|z\rangle=\text{Tr}\left[\rho A\right]=
\langle \alpha|A_{++}|\alpha\rangle + \langle \alpha|A_{+-}|\beta\rangle +
\langle \beta|A_{-+}|\alpha\rangle + \langle \beta|A_{--}|\beta\rangle
$$
Now, the incoherent superposition means that the non-diagonal elements of the density matrix are destroyed (e.g., when tracing out the degrees of the environment inn the overall coherent wave function of photons + environment system.) Then the density matrix becomes
$$
\rho=|z\rangle\langle z|=\begin{bmatrix}|\alpha|^2&0\\
0&|\beta|^2\end{bmatrix}
$$

If the mixture is truly random, wouldn’t we need infinitely many terms with infinitely small probabilities to describe it?

This is not really relevant to the discussion above, but there is nothing wrong with infinitely many terms with infinitely small probabilities. Let us consider a classical wave, which is a superposition of many waves with a completely random phase:
$$
E(x,t)=\sum_i\cos(\omega t-kx +\phi_i)f_i\longrightarrow 
\int d\phi f(\phi) \cos(\omega t-kx +\phi)
$$
In other words, infinitely many terms with infinitely small probabilities is what happens when we weight over a continuous distribution. Note that, the sum of the infinitely many terms with infinitely small probabilities can (and often should) be finite: $\int d\phi f(\phi)=1$
